# Output of ls command

Tags: linux, ls

```
22387281 -rwxr-xr-x 1 john ce0814 8936 5 Oct 13:54 frk
22379635 -rw-r--r-- 1 john ce0814 322 5 Oct 13:53 frk.c
22445178 -rwx------ 1 john users 4 7 Oct 12:05 log.txt
```

What are the first and third columns in this output? I couldn't find descriptions.

Comment: What version of ls is that ?

Comment: -1 for not [telling everyone what you did, and what command options you used](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).

Answer (score 1):

You used `ls -il`.

The `-i` part shows the inode numbers.

From man 1 ls

```
     -i   For each file, print the file's file serial number (inode number).
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognise the first field, but I suspect it might be some kind of file descriptor / unique link.  (How did you generate the command ?).  The third column is the user who owns the file, while the 4th column is the group that owns the files.

Comment: He used the -i` option, probably when (s)he wanted -l but had notes with bad kerning.